# Confluent jdbc connector Cannot make incremental queries using timestamp columns

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Loading of connector:

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-source-test",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=password",
    "table.whitelist":"test",
    "mode": "timestamp",
    "timestamp.column.name":"create_time",
    "topic.prefix": "test-mysql-jdbc-",
    "name":"jdbc-source-test"
  }
}
```

Put next message to the log:

```
[2018-12-12 17:33:14,225] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=jdbc-source-test-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Cannot make incremental queries using timestamp columns [create_time] on `test`.`test` because all of these columns nullable.
```

What I suggest it doens't work because this column has type bigint(20). Is there any workarounds for this?
Confluent version - 5.0.1.

Comment: I think the important part of the message is: _"because all of these columns nullable"_, so what is the DDL of the table, and what happens if you make that column `not null`?

Comment: it actually is defined as not null. as workaround it was advised to write VIEW where this column will be translated to timestamp

Comment: If you're using Mysql as a source, I might suggest using Debezium connector instead of JDBC

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error on Postgresql, and setting the timestamp column mentioned in the error NOT NULL in the database fixed it.

Another option is to use `validate.non.null`: `false` in the connector configuration.

> `validate.non.null`: By default, the JDBC connector will validate that
> all incrementing and timestamp tables have NOT NULL set for the
> columns being used as their ID/timestamp.
>
> If the tables don’t, JDBC connector will fail to start. Setting this
> to false will disable these checks.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to fix this issue, adding the  "validate.non.null": "false" into the config

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-source-test",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=password",
    "table.whitelist":"test",
    "mode": "timestamp",
    "timestamp.column.name":"create_time",
    "topic.prefix": "test-mysql-jdbc-",


     "validate.non.null": "false"

  }
}
```